# What is Oracle Cloud Marketplace? Is it something like Google Play Store where many apps are available to download?

Tags: oracle, cloud

1. What is Oracle Cloud Marketplace? Is it something like Google Play
   Store where many apps are available to download?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Answer (score 1):

When everything else fails, read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/marketplace/marketplace-cloud/appst/whats-oracle-cloud-marketplace.html#GUID-BC48BE32-949F-4B3B-8EDE-FE59F423FCDF).

> Oracle Cloud Marketplace is an online store—a one-stop shop—selling hundreds of business apps and professional services that complement your existing Oracle Cloud implementation.

> All apps and services on the marketplace are offered by approved, registered, and expert partners and developers. Plus, Oracle has vetted, reviewed, and approved each product.